# Loop Through .FILE type files in folder to load into Excel

Tags: excel, csv, file, load

I have a folder that has many files as File Type.  They open in excel or notepad as a csv file when I open individually.  I need to open them into excel so that I can load them into an Access database.  I can’t find away to load directly to Access because of the FILE extension. The below code works if I use the exact file name (example: \Users\Documents\LoadFiles\ABC1_P9009) but it is the yellow highlighted in the code that is causing the error:  “Run-Time error ‘1004’: [DataFormat.Error] Illegal characters in path.”  I’ve tried solving this a few ways:  Dir("\Users\Documents\LoadFiles*ABC*") or
Dir("\Users\Documents\LoadFiles\ABC*.csv")
\Users\Documents\LoadFiles

Sub LoopAllFilesInAFolder()

'Loop through all files in a folder
Dim FileName As Variant

FileName = Dir("\Users\Documents\LoadFiles\ABC*")

While FileName <> ""

```
'Insert the actions to be performed on each file
ActiveWorkbook.Queries("IMPORT").Delete
```

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="IMPORT", Formula:= _
"let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "  Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""\Users\Documents\LoadFiles\ABC *""),[Delimiter=""|"", Columns=30, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type t" & _
"ext}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", type text}, {""Column7"", type text}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}, {""Column12"", type text}, {""Column13"", type text}, {""Column14"", type text}, {""Column15"", type text}, {""Column16"", type text}, {""Column17"", type text}, {""Column18"", t" & _
"ype text}, {""Column19"", type text}, {""Column20"", type text}, {""Column21"", type text}, {""Column22"", type text}, {""Column23"", type text}, {""Column24"", type text}, {""Column25"", Int64.Type}, {""Column26"", type number}, {""Column27"", type date}, {""Column28"", Int64.Type}, {""Column29"", type text}, {""Column30"", type text, filename}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
"OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=IMPORT;Extended Properties=""""" _
, Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
.CommandType = xlCmdSql
.CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [IMPORT]")
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = True
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.BackgroundQuery = True
.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.PreserveColumnInfo = True
.ListObject.DisplayName = "IMPORT"
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
'This example will print the file name to the immediate window
Debug.Print FileName

```
'Set the fileName to the next file
FileName = Dir
```

Wend

End Sub

Any assistance would be wonderful.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to convert the Windows FILE type to csv and link the file into Access using the below code:
Sub ConvertToTXT()
'This converts the Windows FILE type to csv in the File Explorer
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String

strPath = "\Users\Documents\LoadFiles"
strFile = Dir(strPath & "ABC*")

Do While Len(strFile) > 0
If Left(strFile, 4) = "ABC" Then
Name ("\Users\Documents\LoadFiles" & strFile) As (""\Users\Documents\LoadFiles" & strFile & ".csv")
End If
strFile = Dir
Loop

Call ITdataLinkFile

End Sub
Public Function ITdataLinkFile()
''''This links the csv files into the Access db
'Variable Declaration
Dim sTblNm As String
Dim sFilePath As String
Dim sfilename As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tbldef As DAO.TableDef

'Find and delete any prior linked tables
Set db = CurrentDb() 'Set the database object

```
'Set the warnings off to suppress messages
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

For Each tbldef In db.TableDefs
    'here you can use equal to or not equal to delete or keep specific tables
    If Left(tbldef.Name, 4) = "ABC" Then
          Debug.Print tbldef.Name
          sTblNm = tbldef.Name
          'delete Table
          DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, sTblNm
    End If
    
Next tbldef

'Specify File Path
sFilePath = "\Users\Documents\LoadFiles"

'Check for back slash
If Right(sFilePath, 1) <> "\" Then
    sFilePath = sFilePath & "\"
End If
    
sfilename = Dir(sFilePath & "*.csv")

Do While Len(sfilename) > 0
    If Left(sfilename, 4) = "ABC" Then
    DoCmd.TransferText acLinkDelim, , Trim(Replace(sfilename, "*.csv", "")), sFilePath & sfilename, False
    End If
    'Set the fileName to the next available file
    sfilename = Dir
Loop
MsgBox "All files linked", vbInformation
```

End Function

This solves this question.  Thanks.